Return value from specific javascript function in Playwright
I need to extract value that was created after running some script. My tests are written in Playwright.
So, I have a javascript that return some id from locator on page. it looks like
cy.sdk.engine.block.findBy('image') 

This returns id of image. I've tested this script in devtools console and it works.
The question is, how to get this value to display in Playwright test results and verify if the script executed properly.
I'm trying this code:
await page.evaluate(()=> cy.sdk.engine.block.findBy('image'));

Playwright executes it but I don't see value that was created after executing script.

What's cy? Are you combining Cypress with Playwright? If so, why? I think this post needs more context for what you're trying to achieve and code, preferably a [mcve]. Note that evaluate can't return anything but JSON serializable data, so if findBy() returns an object, this won't work--you'll need to drill down to a property.

yes, this is cypress script that return value.  We have 2 test frameworks - cypress and playwright.  All I need is playwright code that execute cypress script and gets value from it.

All right, well did you try following my advice and access a property on findBy()? I'm still waiting for a [mcve] and context for why you want to use a strange pattern of calling Cypress from Playwright--Playwright can already retrieve elements very nicely with locators, which auto-wait. This looks like a very unusual pattern. Thanks.

Imagine mentioned script is not cypress, its just a script that returns value.  Also, Can you provide examples of findBy() in Playwright? I don't understand how it works.
I specifically don't want to use Playwright for this locator because I already have the cypress script for that.

findBy is Cypress (or something; I'm not familiar with Cypress), not Playwright. I don't know what it returns, but "returns value" is unclear. If that value isn't JSON serializable, you'll get nothing. You need to drill down to a JSON serializable property.

the returned value in console is id. It looks like that: '[10485769] 0: 10485769 length: 1 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)'.  the number 10485769 is the id I need to extract.

That's an array, so [0] accesses the first index. It should be serializable though and possible to return. Need a runnable [mcve] to be able to help.

Actually, I rerwritten my tests to use only Playwright, you were right that combining playwright and cypress is a bad decision. Thanks for your time!

Sure, feel free to do a self-answer.
